# Ist "strunzdumm" eine neuere Wortschöpfung?

Tags: etymology

Ich bin gerade bei Twitter über das Wort **strunzdumm** gestolpert.

Mir ist das Wort nicht geläufig. Bei [Google ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strunzdumm&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=8&smoothing=3) finde ich es nicht, wohl aber im [Duden Online](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/strunzdumm) kennt es.

Wer weiß etwas über Herkunft oder Verbreitung?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ich kenn den Ausdruck seit bestimmt dreißig Jahren. Ich weiß nicht, ob das bei Dir als "neu" durchgeht ;)

Wie Dein Duden-Link schon aussagt, geht der Ausdruck auf "[strunzen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/strunzen_prahlen_angeben_protzen)" zurück, ein Synonym für "prahlen". Das Wort wird mehr in der südwestlichen Ecke verwendet. Nordöstler brauchen es also nicht zu kennen :)

Comment: Faszinierend. Seit jeher war ich der festen Überzeugung, "strunzen" bedeute "urinieren". Da habe ich wohl unbewusst ganz intuitiv vermutet, dass die Bedeutung von "strullern" und "brunzen" sich auch in dieser scheinbaren Mischform der zwei Wörter wiederfindet ;)

Answer (score 3):

*Dummer Strunzer* oder *strunzedumm* ist unter anderem im Hessischen bzw. im Rhein-Main-Gebiet seit Jahrzehnten umgangssprachlich bekannt.
Also nicht neu und auch nicht altneu.

Answer (score 2):

Eben bin ich über ein langobardisches, also germanisches, Wort gestolpert, das die Langobarden nach Italien als Invasoren mitgebracht haben. Dieses Wort "strunz" ist im italienischen Schimpfwort "stronzo" aufgegangen, das so etwas wie Idiot heißt. Oft ist ja die Verbindung eines unbekannten Wortes mit einem modernen ein Zeichen davon, dass ersteres sehr alt ist und irgendwann nicht mehr verstanden wurde, so dass man es mit seinem Synonym kombiniert hat. Ah, strunz hieß offenbar so viel wie Kot: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_longobarda

Comment: Jetzt wird mir endlich klar, was Trappatoni mit "Strunz" meinte ;-) Vgl. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ub1zsUD7UNQ ab 01:59.

Answer (score 0):

Beim Alter von Wörtern kann der NGram-Viewer von Google oft sehr hilfreich sein. Ich erhalte damit dieses Ergebnis:

[image: Google NGram "strunzdumm"]
<sup>[Quelle](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strunzdumm&year_start=1970&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3)</sup>

In gedruckten und von Google gescannten Dokumenten findet man das Wort "strunzdumm" offenbar ab Mitte der 1980er-Jahre, und das deckt sich auch mit meiner persönlichen Wahrnehmung. Ich glaube, es das erste Mal Mitte der 1980er-Jahre in einem Kinofilm aus deutscher Produktion gehört zu haben (»Supernasen«, »Otto - Der Film« oder etwas in dieser Art). Ich kann mich da aber auch irren.

---

Laut [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/strunzdumm) ist das Wort ein *»Kompositum aus dem Stamm des Verbs strunzen und dem Adjektiv dumm«.* Das Verb [strunzen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/strunzen) hat nach derselben Quelle zwei Bedeutungen:

1. **urinieren**
   Diese Bedeutung ist mir geläufig. Laut Wiktionary ist dieses Verb *westdeutsch*, ich habe es aber auch schon aus dem Mund gebürtiger Österreicher gehört (zugegebenermaßen aber selten).
2. **mit einer Sache angeben, sie prahlerisch übertreiben**
   Diese Bedeutung war mir bis gerade eben völlig unbekannt. Laut Wiktionary ist das Verb mit dieser Bedeutung *südwestdeutsch*.

Beides ergibt für mich als Teil von *»strunzdumm«* aber nicht besonders viel Sinn.